# Getting photos from MobileSync data created by iTunes

Tags: itunes, windows, photos

My wife had an iPhone 4, which she synched with a PC using iTunes.  Both the phone and the PC are gone, but I have backups of the PC, including the folder where I believe iTunes kept copies of her photos:

`C:\users\herusername\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync`

We don't currently own either an iPhone or an Apple computer.  Is it possible to retrieve the photos from the files in this folder, using only a PC?

Comment: i can't really provide an answer, but this is one area where Apple says [you can't do it](https://support.apple.com/HT204215), so a whole swathe of 3rd parties have released apps that say they can. Just google "how do i retrieve photos from itunes backup?" & only test ones with free trials, to make sure it works. Don't pay for anything up front.

Answer (score 1):

In the MobileSync folder, go into the Backup folder which will probably just contain a pile of folders and files.

Open these files in some type of Media Player (Quicktime is probably the best option).

There may be of items once you open them, but if you sort by size you should get video, audio, and photos to float to the top.

Comment: What if backups are encrypted?

Comment: Then you won't be able to recover them without a device to connect to iTunes to restore it to, which would allow you to verify your password to decrypt them. So with only a PC and no other devices, then you would not be able to recover them in they're encrypted, probably even with third party apps.

Comment: The 3rd party apps claim to be able to decrypt. Search "how do i retrieve photos from itunes encrypted backup?" I'm not going to get one just to find out, but this is why I commented rather than provide an inaccurate answer.